# Using 'Ajax updated' dataset with crossfilter

Tags: ajax, json, dynamic, crossfilter

I have a really large dataset (about 500 000 records...) about the CO2 emission on London that I want to display with maps and charts using crossfilter.
For reasons of performance, I want to do queries beforehand by boroughs, so I've done an ajax function that does that dynamically when I click on a borough (just imagine a map of london with borough boundaries where we can click on them).
The Ajax code works fine :

```
function load_data(str){
var londonData = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/london-data.php",
        data: "name='"+str+"'",
        type: 'get',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            londonData = data;
        }
    });
alert(JSON.stringify(londonData));

return londonData;}
```

It returns a json file. When I click on a borough, the alert function shows me that the data updated.
But to use crossfilter, I wanted to have a global variable that updates when you click on a borough, thanks to the load_data function, but it doesn't work -> the variable keeps the same value as it was initialized.

I don't know if I'm clear enough but do you think there is a solution to update this global variable, and as a consequence to update the crossfilter data? Something like :

```
layer.on("click", function (e) {
             londonData = load_data(/*name of the layer clicked on*/)
        });
dataset = crossfilter(londonData);
```

At the end I'd like that my charts updates when I click on a borough, so the 'dataset' variable has to change when I click on one. Don't know if it's possible or if I'm doing completely wrong...
Anyway Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think since the ajax request is asynchronous , you have to apply the crossfilter function  in the success function. Thus you create and use your crossfilter data only after your ajax data is loaded.